# A reasonably-priced Thunderbolt PCIe enclosure

Tags: pcie, thunderbolt

I am looking to play some games on my MacBook Pro and would like to add an external GPU to it. Searching around I found that a Thunderbolt to PCIe enclosure works fine for that purpose, however all the ones I found seem extremely expensive for what is essentially a power brick, connectors and an aluminium box.

Does anyone know of a more reasonably priced option ? I'd hate to put more money into the enclosure than the GPU itself.

Comment: You can build one yourself or you can shell out. I tried a few years ago to design a prototype for this that could actually be manufactured for a reasonable cost. It's just not feasible.

Comment: Did you see https://egpu.io ?

Comment: @SEJPM just checked it out. Still expensive as it lists the same models I've found by myself, the "cheapest" being an Akitio one at 220$.

Comment: @jcam3 care to elaborate? What's the most expensive part in those, excluding R&D? It's essentially a power brick and a Thunderbolt to PCIe chip that should cost a few bucks when bought in volume, right?

Comment: @AndréBorie I thought the same thing as you but the problem was that all of the affordable PCI-E riser/expansion modules I could find had bottlenecks that would require re-wiring and soldering to remove. They get all choked up by a USB 3.0 output port/x16 to x1/whatever. All the backend work made it unattractive for both the finances and the sheer amount of extra work. If I remember right my starting capacity would be maybe 7-10 units/week in near-perfect conditions. Anything I found with sufficient end-to-end throughput was too expensive to be financially viable. This was 3-4 years ago.

Comment: @jcam3 oh so you used an off-the-shelf PCIe expansion module - did you try calculating how much it would cost (at scale) to manufacture your own PCB? Again I expect the only active component (the single chip that translates between Thunderbolt and PCIe) to only cost a few bucks.

Comment: @AndréBorie I never got deep into running those numbers because the up-front labor was just not going to be worth it for me. It may have ended up being profitable, but I value my free time more than my early projections said I'd be making per unit of time worked.